# how to change stage size dynamically

Tags: android, actionscript-3, air, flash-cs5

I am all new to flash for android so it would be grateful to get help my problem.

I made a flash game with stage size **1024 x 768** for my desktop using `AIR 2.6`. Now I want to try my this game on my android tablet without changing the resolution and aspect ratio.

I used `this.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_BORDER;` it did keep the aspect ratio but cut off some side part of my game. I would like to know if there is a code to change my game resolution according to devices, without having  manually to change my game resolution..

Answer (score 0):

Handle multiple scree resolutions in android for images:

1. In android Application project anatomy 4 folder 1) `hdpi`, `mdpi`, `ldpi` and `xhdpi` (in res folder ) you can put your images here for multiple screen size devices. The system automatically choose images from these folder according to device.
2. Use `9patch` images.
3. Avoid using of `AbsoluteLayout`.
4. use `.png` images.
5. use `layout-land` folder for landscape mode.

Thanks.